# How can I delete a directory and all files in it with C++?

Tags: c++, file, directory

How can I delete all the files in the directory? I've used rmdir and other methods suggested in the internet but no one helped me: this is one of them: (I want to remove directory tmp in the current work directory)

```
removeDir()
{
         char currentPath[_MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentPath(currentPath);
    std::string tmp(currentPath);

    string path = tmp + "\\temp";


    std::string command = "del  ";
    std::string Path = path + "1.txt"; 
    cout << Path << endl;
    system(command.append(Path).c_str());   
}

GetCurrentPath(char* buffer)
{
    getcwd(buffer, _MAX_PATH);
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/

> ```
>  int remove ( const char * filename );
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  if( remove( "myfile.txt" ) != 0 )
    perror( "Error deleting file" );
  else
    puts( "File successfully deleted" );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP and I evidently speak a secret language, since he accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

[Use Boost Filesystem Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: @fali boost::filesystem::remove_all("directory"); Start associating yourself with the boost world. Reinventing the wheel is not smart most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [Boost Filesystem Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which provides a number of features that make this sort of thing a lot easier. The example code on the linked page does something very similar to what you want to accomplish (it searches a directory recursively instead of deleting contents recursively).

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't wanna use Boost, you can do this

```
rm -r "folder name"
```